# Any ideas why excel interop reads many decimals as -2146826246?

Tags: .net, excel, office-interop

I'm absolutely sure that I haven't changed a thing.

For some reason, excel interop has started reading cells with decimals with same mystic value:

> -2146826246

I'm absolutely clueless on what to do next, what to look for.

OS: windows7 enterprise edition, MSOffice: 2010 professional plus

Any ideas what this could be?

Recent updates:

[image]

Comment: Are any windows updates were installed recently? You can see it in the Updates History

Comment: @sll there are. "Update for MSOffice 2010 (KB2345000) 2011.09.15" looks suspicious. think I should rollback it?

Comment: yep, try it out. Anyway Windows propose you to install it again so you can restore it easily;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not that unusual.  When you convert it to hex, you get 0x800A07FA.  Which is an *error code*.  The last 4 digits is the Excel error, producing 2042.  Google "Excel error 2042", first hit tells you it means "match not found" or "#N/A".

That's as much as I can reverse-engineer.  Start by taking a critical look at the error handling in your code.  Don't mess with the install.

Comment: Now that's interesting. When I think about it, common thing for those cells is that their values are calculated by excel formulas. Might be that underneath excel holds value "#N/A" cause it can't sum cells mentioned in formula. Definitely this expands area for some further research - thanks. (p.s. didn't mess with updates yet, just using for testing another seemingly same fashioned excel which somehow can be read no problems).

Comment: Did auto-recalc get turned off?

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Excel Interop but this appears to be related to a limitation of .net's understanding of Excel's various CVErr values.

There is an excellent write up on this at: [dealing with cverr values](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-%E2%80%93-part-i-the-problem/)